# Application Commands for a discord Roll Bot

Tags: python, discord

I wanted to write Application Commands for my Discord (Dice D&D) bot. This means that when I enter a command like /H, the bot should suggest which commands it has available. Unfortunately, it's not working at all, and I have no idea why. I have the code, but if someone had a Python basic structure for it, I could complete it. The code is below and I know that the code is not working (and is dumb). I know that the code must be in json but my bot works on Python.

```py
async def roll_command(data):
    # Implement the roll command logic here
    pass


async def weapon_command(data):
    # Implement the weapon command logic here
    pass


async def skill_command(data):
    # Implement the skill command logic here
    pass


async def help_command(data):
    # Implement the help command logic here
    pass


async def command_entry(request):
    # Read the request body as text (str)
    raw_data = await request.text()

    # Get our header values
    signature = request.headers.get("x-signature-ed25519")
    timestamp = request.headers.get("x-signature-timestamp")
    if signature is None or timestamp is None:
        # We can't verify the request without the signature and timestamp
        return web.HTTPUnauthorized()

    try:
        # Verify the signature with our public key
        PUBLIC_KEY.verify(f"{timestamp}{raw_data}".encode(), bytes.fromhex(signature))
    except BadSignatureError:
        # The signature is wrong
        return web.HTTPUnauthorized()

    # Parse the request body as json
    data = json.loads(raw_data)

    # Check which interaction type this request is
    if data["type"] == 1:
        # It's a PING request -> respond with PONG (type 1)
        return web.json_response({"type": 1})

    elif data["type"] == 2:
        # It's a command request -> run the correct command
        command = data["data"]
        if command["name"] == "roll":
            return await roll_command(data)

        if command["name"] == "Waffe":
            return await weapon_command(data)

        if command["name"] == "Skill":
            return await skill_command(data)

        if command["name"] == "Hilfe":
            return await help_command(data)

        else:
            # We don't know this command
            return web.HTTPNotFound()

    else:
        # We don't know what to do with this
        return web.HTTPBadRequest()


async def create_commands(app):
    # The JSON structure of the commands
    commands = [
        {
            "name": "roll",
            "description": "Roll a dice",
            "options": []  # The command doesn't need any arguments
        },
        {
            "name": "Waffe",
            "description": "Get weapon information",
            "options": [
                {
                    "type": 3,  # It's a text argument,
                    "name": "name",
                    "description": "The name of the weapon",
                    "required": True,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Skill",
            "description": "Get skill information",
            "options": [
                {
                    "type": 3,  # It's a text argument,
                    "name": "name",
                    "description": "The name of the skill",
                    "required": True,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Hilfe",
            "description": "Get help information",
            "options": []  # The command doesn't need any arguments
        }
    ]

    # We need a session to make HTTP requests
    session = ClientSession()

    # Make the request to the Discord API
    async with session.put(
            f"https://discord.com/api/v8/applications/{CLIENT_ID}/guilds/{GUILD_ID}/commands",
            headers={"Authorization": f"Bot {token}"},
            json=commands
    ) as resp:
        # If something goes wrong, raise an error
        resp.raise_for_status()

    # We don't need the session anymore
    await session.close()


app = web.Application()  # Create a web application
app.add_routes([web.post("/entry", command_entry)])  # Add the command route at /entry
app.on_startup.append(create_commands)  # Run create_commands before starting up the app
web.run_app(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)  # Start the app and bind to 127.0.0.1:8080
```